# How to update record consisting of dependent tables using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can list and create records, but can't update the records. When I run my project and click the Edit button on listed records, form page appears, but if I click Submit after completing the form, I get page not found error in same URL.

I can list and create records, but can't update the records. When I run my project and click the Edit button on listed records, form page appears, but if I click Submit after completing the form, I get page not found error in same URL.

[image: 1]

**CustomerAddressModel**

```
namespace PharmacyManagmentV2.Models
{
    public class CustomerAdressModel
    {
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public Address address { get; set; }
       

      
    }
}
```

**CustomerController**

```
namespace PharmacyManagmentV2.Areas.Application.Controllers
{
    [Area("Application")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDBContext _context;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Address> _address;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<Customer> _customer;

        public CustomerController(AppDBContext context,
            IGenericRepository<Address> address,
            IGenericRepository<Customer> customer)
        {
            _context = context;
            _address = address;
            _customer = customer;
        }

        // GET: Application/Customer
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var appDBContext = _customer.GetAll().Include(c => c.Address);
            return View(await appDBContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Application/Customer/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var model = new  CustomerAdressModel();
            model.customer = await _customer.GetAll()
                .Include(c => c.Address)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            model.address = await _address.GetAll()
                .Include(m => m.AspNetUsers)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == model.customer.AddressId);
            if (model.customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Application/Customer/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Application/Customer/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CustomerAdressModel model)
        {
           

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               await _address.Create(model.address);
               await _customer.Create(new Customer()
                {
                    Address = model.address
                });
                await _address.SaveChanges();
                await _customer.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Application/Customer/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var model = new CustomerAdressModel();
            model.customer = await _customer.GetById(id.Value);
            model.address = await _address.GetById(model.customer.AddressId.Value);
            if (model.customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Application/Customer/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, CustomerAdressModel model)
        {
            if (id != model.customer.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _customer.Update(model.customer);
                    await _customer.SaveChanges();

                    await _address.Update(model.address);
                    await _address.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CustomerExists(model.customer.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Application/Customer/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var customer = await _context.Customers
                .Include(c => c.Address)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Application/Customer/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Customers.Remove(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool CustomerExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Customers.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model PharmacyManagmentV2.Models.CustomerAdressModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Application/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Edit</h1>
<h4>CustomerViewModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit" >
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.Balance" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.Balance" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.Balance" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.Gender" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.Gender" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.DateofBird" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.DateofBird" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.DateofBird" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.customer.Phone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.customer.Phone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.customer.Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.address.City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.address.City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.address.City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.address.State" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.address.State" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.address.State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.address.Zip" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.address.Zip" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.address.Zip" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.address.Address1" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.address.Address1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.address.Address1" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.address.Address2" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.address.Address2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.address.Address2" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace PharmacyManagmentV2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
          
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
            {
                opt.Cookie.Name = "CookieSettings";
                opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            opt =>
            {
                opt.Cookie.Name = "CookieSettings";
                opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            services.AddScoped<IAddressRepository, AddressRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILeafRepository, LeafRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IManufacturerRepository, ManufacturerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMedicineRepository, MedicineRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMedicineTypeRepository, MedicineTypeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPurchaseRepository, PurchaseRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISellRepository, SellRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitRepository, UnitRepository>();
           
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>),typeof(GenericRepository <>));
         

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Application}/{controller=Customer}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Login",
                    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Register",
                    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "application_home",
                    pattern: "{area=Application}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "customer_list",
                     pattern: "{area=Application}/{controller=Customer}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "customer_edit",
                     pattern: "{area=Application}/{controller=Customer}/{action=Edit}/{id?}");

                
            });

            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to show your controller too

Comment: it says: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Sorry, but I  can't see your controller header, only actions

Comment: I rewrote the text to pass warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] at your action try to add
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
 <form asp-action="Edit" >
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
```

or remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]